# Be able to add and item in a drop down list if it is not present

Tags: list, asp.net-core, dropdown

I have a drop down list containing city names. I would like the user to be able to add in their city if it is not present in the list, and then that must then persist in the database? 
I am Using ASP.NET core

[image]

Comment: First check database and save the city and then update drop down list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example based on your requirement.
City.cs class:

```
 public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(_context.City, "Id", "CityName");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(City city)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || _context.City.Where(x => x.CityName == city.CityName).Count() > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(_context.City, "Id", "CityName");
            return View();
        }
        _context.City.Add(city);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```html
@model WebApplication_core.Models.City
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>SelectIndex</h1>

<select asp-for="Id"
        asp-items="@ViewBag.Cities">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
<h4>add your city</h4>
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CityName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="CityName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CityName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Result of this demo:
[image]

Comment: This was so very helpful!!! Thank you ever so much for your kind assistance. I will be marking this as the answer !  Kind regards, Luke.